# Cast collection of generic type to collection of non-generic type in C#

Tags: c#, generics, casting

Given this type:

```
public class DataRow
{

}
public class DataRow<T> : DataRow
{

}
```

And this use of it:

```
public class DataRowCollection
{
    public IList<DataRow> List{get;set;}
}
public class DataRowCollection<T> : DataRowCollection
{
    public new IList<DataRow<T>> List{get;set;}
}
```

Why can't I assign `base.List` to `this.List` in `DataRowCollection<T>` ? And why can't I cast `this.List` to the non-generic type and assign to `base.List` ?

**Edit**: the code that is failing in `DataRowCollection<T>`

```
base.List = (IList<DataRow>)this.List;
```

(The cast fails)

```
base.List = this.List;
```

(Compiler error)

Comment: Could you show the assignments that are failing? This looks like a (co)variance issue.

Comment: Sorry, will edit - both inherit etc...

Comment: If its the *cast* (not the assignment) thats failing, it could be because you are casting a `IList<DataRowType>` to `IList<DataRow>` directly (which will never work). You could use .Cast<> (a LINQ function) to convert everything if that is your only problem. You may still have a variance issue though.

Comment: Say you have `DataRow<X>` and `DataRow<Y>` and your base `IList<DataRow>` is *actually* a `IList<DataRow<X>>`. If everything worked like you wanted it to, via your base reference, you should be able to add `DataRow<Y>` to it, yet that would clearly be illegal. You need a better design.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I understand what you're saying. However the accepted answer was correct for me. I'll live with my bad design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `IList` is invariant, and not covariant or contravariant with respect to its generic type.

If that cast were valid then you could add a `DataRow<SomeTypeThatIsNotT>` to the list, which would be breaking the contract of that `IList`.

Comment: Thanks. I changed "IList" to "IEnumerable" in the base class which worked perfectly.